# WARNING: Unchecked return value from library (CHECKED_RETURN)

Tags: c++

I am getting warning for this code:

```
void filepermission(void)
{
     chmod("/file.txt",S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
}
```

The warning is

> Calling chmod("/file.txt", 256U) without checking return value. This library function may fail and return an error code.

How can I remove this warning?  Is this the right way to remove this warning?

```
void filepermission(void){
if(chmod("/file.txt",S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) == 0){
    ;
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is just to remove the compile time warning then one way is to cast the return value to void:

```
void filepermission(void)
{
     (void)chmod("/file.txt",S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
}
```

With this cast to void, you are telling the compiler you know there is a return value, but you're intentionally ignoring it, and you're prepared to take the risks associated with doing so, and you don't need to be warned about it.

Of course you then run the risk of your compiler (or static analyser) complaining you're using an old C-style cast in which case you could have it as

```
void filepermission(void)
{
     static_cast<void>(chmod("/file.txt",S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR));
}
```

But in actual fact you should care about the [return value](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chmod) and handle it appropriately

```
void filepermission(void)
{
     if (chmod("/file.txt",S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) != 0)
         std::cout << "Some or other error message\n";
}
```

Comment: What casting here does to remove the warning?

Comment: also could you please tell me , above code which I have shown in the question will give warning or not? @acraig5075

Answer (score 0):

<sub>`chmod` is a non-standard function to set file permissions. If you prefer to write portable code, you could instead use the `filesystem` library that was added to the standard library in C++17.</sub>

`std::filesystem` has a [`permissions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions) function that will throw an exception if setting the permissions fails so you don't have to check this call explicitly, which is practical if you already have exception handling in place. It also has a non-throwing overload if you prefer to check the status manually - and if you use that overload, you *should* check the status. Your program is likely depending on that the call succeeds.

Example using the throwing version:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;   // an alias to avoid a lot of typing

void filepermission() {

    // may throw std::filesystem::filesystem_error
    fs::permissions("file.txt",
                    fs::perms::owner_read | fs::perms::owner_write,
                    fs::perm_options::replace); // set the exact permissions above
}

int main() {
    try {
        filepermission();
        // ...
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
Exception: filesystem error: cannot set permissions: No such file or directory [file.txt]
```